# My Mac can't recognise USB Volume as Start-volume

Tags: catalina

I would like to reset Catalina. The volume with the operating system has been deleted. However, it does not recognise the external USB volume where the latest Catalina version is loaded as a start-up volume. I have now tried to restore the system with a backup from TimeMachine from an external hard drive. Unfortunately, it does not react to this either. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you try boot in internet recovery mode? cmd+alt+r at boot. What is the exact model and year of this Mac?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not react to this either". What exactly fails here?

Comment: cmd+option+R helped. Thank you. It's very strange that I've been in this window several times in the last two days, but nothing has worked. It seems that my old MacPro 2010 is in a good mood today.